# Developing with(out) Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm working on a project where some parts of the system rely on Active Directory. However, I'm at the client's office, where I cannot access their AD(Red tape).

Is there a way to mock AD while I develop?

I'm developing in C# and .NET

Comment: A VM running Windows Server is probably the easiest thing to use.

Comment: "Is there a way to mock AD while I develop?" It depends on what parts of AD you actually rely on. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, our service needs to query the AD for user groups and email addresses. The challenge is that our dev machines are not on the client's domain. I suppose that's where TomTom's answer becomes relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fake Active Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354107/how-to-fake-active-directory)

Answer (score 6):

*our service needs to query the AD for user groups and email addresses*

Another option then would be to implement the AD access with the repository pattern and have at least **two** implementations.

```
public interface IRepository 
{
    IEnumerable<Something> GetUsers();
}

public class ActiveDirectoryRepository : IRepository ...

public class AnotherRepository : IRepository ...
```

This way you could easily switch to required implementation at the deployment time - you develop against database, xmlfiles, memory, anything but the deployed application talks to the AD - because you code against the repository interface, you just reconfigure the application and have ZERO changes in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Active Directory Lightweight Directory Service (used to be called ADAM).  This allows you to setup a multi-user AD environment.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/

Comment: -1. Not possibly - you ahve to redo all the schemata, then you still miss the security part (kerberos).

Comment: +1, another useful answer you downvoted just because you propose a completely different approach. Plus, the OP does not mention kerberos, that's why I asked about it.

Comment: @TomTom: I find your comments slightly offensive. I haven't mention any "Hello Worlds", burgers or anything like that. I respect your experience and I just asked if you ever developed software in distributed teams, where you just HAVE to rely on someone else's code and you don't verify it (it is not your responsibility to test someone else's work). OP clearly mentions he wants to MOCK the AD, isolation or emulation are as good approaches as yours. We don't have to agree but I don't think it is fair to downvote all other answers but yours.

Comment: @TomTom: I respect your opinions and your judgements do not make your opinions more valid. Do we know each other personally maybe? Although I can't be sure (googling "TomTom" doesn't help), I can't believe you would write such an elaboration on me based on this one isolated view on such a specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

And this is where "Professional" and "development environment" comes in.

The client has to have a separate environment for development, with AD servers etc. This is where virtualization comes in VERY handy, to set up a number of small low power virtual machines to run AD and all other required services.

Have one (or more) separate networks, isolated, with separate domains, and develop using them.

Standard practice.