# How can I unit test my Active Directory queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have small functions, which defines the AD connection and a function which creates all queries to find user information.

How can I test functions like this with chai/mocha?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354107/how-to-fake-active-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory uses LDAP protocol for querying. So tou can use an LDAP mock server that starts at the start of the required testing section.
There is a npm package for LDAP mock server that reads the its data from json files:
https://github.com/veo-labs/ldap-server-mock